# Accessing C++ enum variable through javascript function pointer

Tags: c++, node.js, ffi

I am trying to pass a callback function from node.js to a dll written in C++ with the following function.

**dll1.cpp**

```
enum GUIENUM
{
    START = 0,
    STOP,
    DEBUG,
    STATUS,
}GUI_ENUM;

typedef void(*callbackMethod)(GUIENUM GUI_ENUM, const char*);
extern "C" DLL1_API void SetCallBackMethod(callbackMethod callback);
callbackMethod m_callback;

extern "C" DLL1_API void Start();
extern "C" DLL1_API void Stop();

DLL1_API void SetCallBackMethod(callbackMethod callback)
{
    m_callback = callback;
}

DLL1_API void Start()
{
    m_callback(GUIENUM::STATUS, "Start is pressed");
}

DLL1_API void Stop()
{
    m_callback(GUIENUM::STATUS, "stop is pressed");
}
```

and my js files looks like this

**app.js**

```
var ffi =require("ffi-napi")
var ref =require("ref-napi");

var constString = ref.types.CString;
var bool = ref.types.bool;
var enumtest = ref.types.void;
var callback =ffi.Callback(ref.types.void, [enumtest ,constString], function (sec, data) {
      console.log(sec);
      console.log(data);
    });

var libloc="./Dll1.dll";

 const ces = ffi.Library(libloc, {
  'SetCallBackMethod':[ref.types.void, ['pointer']],
  'Start': [ref.types.void,[ ref.types.void]],
  'Stop': [ref.types.void,[ ref.types.void]],
});

module.exports = ces;

ces.SetCallBackMethod(callback)
ces.Start()
ces.Stop()
```

How to pass a C++ enum in a callback function from nodejs. I'm getting an exception in ces.SetCallBackMethod(callback) as Type conversion error. Please suggest me.

Comment: Note: Modern JavaScript prefers `let` and `const` to ES5's `var`.

Comment: `GUIENUM::STATUS` is wrong for the type of `enum` you declared.  `STATUS` is in the same scope as the enum's definition.  You meant to use `enum class`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need to map the `enum` value to the `Number` that JS uses. And then call the callback with that JS value.
In general whenever you are working with JS entities you need to pass JS entities.
I also advice you to use `NAPI` to build native add-ons.